# PDF Generation In Windows app 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-store-apps, postscript

I am trying to generate the pdf file in windows app 8.1 (not windows phone) c#, I have tried with using the postscript because i didn't find any free package to generate the pdf. If there is please let me know.

Here is the sample code which i have tried using postscript,

```
 var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyFirstPdf.pdf", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var stream = await System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(file))
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {

                List<long> xrefs = new List<long>();
                writer.WriteLine("%PDF-1.7");
                writer.Write("%");
                writer.Flush();
                byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, 4);
                stream.Flush();
                writer.WriteLine("");

                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
                writer.WriteLine("1 0 obj");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Catalog");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Pages 2 0 R");
                writer.WriteLine(">>");
                writer.WriteLine("endobj");

                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
                writer.WriteLine("2 0 obj");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Pages");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Kids [3 0 R]");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Count 1");
                writer.WriteLine(">>");
                writer.WriteLine("endobj");

                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
                writer.WriteLine("3 0 obj");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Page");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Parent 2 0 R");
                writer.WriteLine("  /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]");
                // Default userspace units: 72/inch, origin at bottom left  
                writer.WriteLine("  /Resources");
                writer.WriteLine("  <<");
                writer.WriteLine("    /ProcSet [/PDF/Text]");
                // This PDF uses only the Text ability  
                writer.WriteLine("    /Font");
                writer.WriteLine("    <<");
                writer.WriteLine("      /F0 4 0 R");
                // I will define three fonts, #4, #5 and #6  
                writer.WriteLine("      /F1 5 0 R");
                writer.WriteLine("      /F2 6 0 R");
                writer.WriteLine("    >>");
                writer.WriteLine("  >>");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Contents 7 0 R");
                writer.WriteLine(">>");
                writer.WriteLine("endobj");

                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
                writer.WriteLine("4 0 obj");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Font");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Subtype /Type1");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding");
                writer.WriteLine("  /BaseFont /Times-Roman");
                writer.WriteLine(">>");
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
                writer.WriteLine("5 0 obj");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Font");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Subtype /Type1");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding");
                writer.WriteLine("  /BaseFont /Times-Bold");
                writer.WriteLine(">>");
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
                writer.WriteLine("6 0 obj");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Font");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Subtype /Type1");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding");
                writer.WriteLine("  /BaseFont /Times-Italic");
                writer.WriteLine(">>");

                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                //Lables  
                sb.AppendLine("BT");
                sb.AppendLine("/F0 15 Tf");
                sb.AppendLine("20 TL");
                sb.AppendLine("30.0 760.0 Td");
                sb.AppendLine("(testlist demo1)' Tj");
                sb.AppendLine("ET");

                writer.WriteLine("7 0 obj");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Length " + sb.Length);
                writer.WriteLine(">>");
                writer.WriteLine("stream");
                writer.Write(sb.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine("  q");  //added  
                writer.WriteLine("    156 0 0 272 100 200 cm");  
                writer.WriteLine("    /Img1 Do");
                writer.WriteLine("  Q");
                writer.WriteLine("endstream");
                writer.WriteLine("endobj");


                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                dynamic xref_pos = stream.Position;
                writer.WriteLine("xref");
                writer.WriteLine("1 " + xrefs.Count);
                long xref = 0;
                foreach (long xref_loopVariable in xrefs)
                {
                    xref = xref_loopVariable;
                    writer.WriteLine("{0:0000000000} {1:00000} n", xref, 0);
                }

                // PDF-TRAILER. Every PDF ends with this trailer.  
                writer.WriteLine("trailer");
                writer.WriteLine("<<");
                writer.WriteLine("  /Size " + xrefs.Count);
                writer.WriteLine("  /Root 1 0 R");
                writer.WriteLine(">>");
                writer.WriteLine("startxref");
                writer.WriteLine(xref_pos);
                writer.WriteLine("%%EOF");
            }
```

Yes, It works fine and generate the pdf which works properly in microsoft edge but while opening that same file with adobe reader it is giving blank output..

Another Solution i have tried using PDFDocument but in that also i am getting same problem.

Please Help me out. Awaiting Response.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: have look on [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa), it might help!

Comment: Itextsharp is a good library for PDF manipulation

Comment: Your code is not generating PostScript, its PDF, there are significant differences ! If you can generate PostScirpt (which Windows itself can do from the print system) then Ghostscript can create a PDF file from that. I cna't really tell you what's wrong with the PDF file you produce, because you haven't put it anywhere. Post it somewhere public and probably I can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @KenS i dnt have that much reputation for posting file.. can u suggest me any storage website where i can or can u give me ur emailId?

Comment: well dropbox is fine, or any file sharing service really provided its not going to serve up malware at the same time :-)

Comment: @KenS check file here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyl09bky3bzggoj/MyFirstPdf.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK There are a number of problems here. A minor point is that your file has 3 bytes of garbage binary before the file begins. Possibly this is a UTF BOM or something. PDF readers are supposed to skip that, but its worth getting it right. Opening the file with a binary editor I see it starts 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF 0x25 0x50....

Secondly the xref is incorrect:

```
xref
1 7
0000000020 65536 n
0000000079 00000 n
0000000149 00000 n
0000000382 00000 n
0000000489 00000 n
0000000595 00000 n
0000000703 00000 n
```

You are starting that cross-reference subsection from 1, you ought to start it from 0, and 0 ought to be the head of the linked list of free objects. See the PDF reference page 93 onwards. The xref **should** look something like:

```
xref
0 8
0000000000 00000 f
0000000020 00000 n
0000000079 00000 n
0000000149 00000 n
0000000382 00000 n
0000000489 00000 n
0000000595 00000 n
0000000703 00000 n
```

So that's 8 entries, numbered from 0 to 7, entry 0 is the head of the linked list of free entries, and so is marked as free.

Congratulations on getting the length of each entry correct, that's a fault many people fall over.

A corollary is that the /Size entry in the trailer dictionary should be 8, not 7:

```
trailer
<<
  /Size 8
  /Root 1 0 R
>>
```

The content stream (object 7) is declared as having a length of 63 bytes, whereas in fact its 115 bytes.

The content stream contains:

```
(testlist demo1)' Tj
```

removing the extraneous ' resolves that problem.

Finally (for now) you have attempted to use an XObject:

```
/Img1 Do
```

But you have not declared the XObject 'Img1' in the Resources dictionary of the page, and in fact you have not defined the XObject anywhere in the file, so that's simply not going to work.

I suspect that's enough to be going on with :-)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...I made corrections as you suggested, but didn't got first point.. can u please explain or tell me how to fix it because after solving other issues still m not able to open in adobe reader.

Comment: By first point, do you mean the bytes before the header, or the xref table ? There may be other problems as well, those are the ones I spotted so far....

Comment: Well for the bytes before the header, you have to simply not write those bytes. My guess is its the fact that you are opening a file System.Text.Encoding.UTF8. I presume that's writing a byte order mark. You'll have to open it raw, or binary or whatever. I have no clue about C# so you're on your own there.

Comment: Your 'startxref' is also incorrect, its 876 and should be 873. That offset is measured from the start of the file, the '%' in %PDF. Because you've got 3 bytes of binary at the start the calculation is incorrect. That also makes all the offsets in the xref table incorrect, if you fix the emission of the garbage bytes, then it should work out OK.

Comment: when i tried to remove that bytes then adobe gave me error "file is damaged" :D

Comment: I mean the 3 bytes at the start of the file before the %PDF.... This is my version of your file with the various errors corrected https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1qh613ko6u4bgc/MyFirstPDF-fixed.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it worked like a charm... but whenever i am adding new BT & ET For another Content again m facing the same issue because i dnt knw how to write this postscript code in c#.. do u know any tool which can track errors like jsfiddler?

Comment: You aren't writing PostScript, you are writing PDF! The two are not the same, not at all. There are no really good syntax checkers for PDF files, even the ones that exist won't usually tell you exactly what is wrong. Fundamentally, if you want to write a PDF creation tool you are just going to have to learn PDF syntax.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort which you have done so far for me. But i have very short time to complete it. So i think i have to choose another way to generate the pdf. Do you know any alternatives to generate pdf from windows Apps. Those solutions are also welcomed. :)

Comment: As I understand it, recent versions of Windows can 'print' to PDF' natively (this may be a Windows 10 feature, I am not certain). Or as I already said, you can print to PostScript file using the Windows print system, and then use Ghostscript to create a PDF file from the PostScript. There are also innumerable PDF libraries, such as pdftk, Poppler, PDFBox, I have no doubt there are others.